# Apply a usage charge from the job file

Tags: laravel, shopify-app

I want to apply usage charges from the Job file. I have referred to this [documentation](https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/Creating-a-Billable-App#creating-usage-charges), but I can't find a way to run this URL from the job file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation helps you to display a payment view to the user.
You can't produce a view in a Job and display it to the user, because Jobs are run in background.

You will need to execute this code in a Controller method.

Otherwise, if you **need** to have it in a Job, you will need to charge the user using differently (using an Intent for instance).